# Why is my Giphy API's POST request returning status 400?

Tags: javascript, post, http-status-code-400, giphy-api

I'm trying to upload a gif from the webcam feed to Giphy through their API and it returns status 400 - "Please supply a file upload or a 'source_image_url'". My function does this:

```
upload = new FormData();
upload.append("file", gif, "usergif.gif");
console.log(upload.get("file"));

fetch("https://upload.giphy.com/v1/gifs?file=" upload + "&api_key=" + apiKey, { method: "POST" })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.status);
        return response.json;
    }
)
```

The `gif` variable inside `upload.append()` has a value of `recorder.getBlob()` (I'm using the RecorderRTC API), I also tried to use as a source `upload.file` and even `upload.get("file")`, also used `URL.createObjectUrl(gif)` and changed `file=` for `source_image_url=` in the fetch request, even tried to send the `gif` variable without the use of `FormData()` but nothing worked.

Do you have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, the solution was that when using the POST method, you gotta specify a `body` header with the file to be uploaded